# SQLite EF Code First - "System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: bad parameter or other API misuse"

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, system.data.sqlite

I'm trying to migrate a WPF desktop application database with EF code first migrations from SQL Server CE to SQLite. The application is running .Net 4.7.2 and EF6 and requires the data to be encrypted.

I've opted to use `System.Data.SQLite` and `SQLite.CodeFirst` (https://github.com/msallin/SQLiteCodeFirst) as this should support both encrypted database and code first migrations, and require minimal changes.

The application builds but at runtime when the database context is accessed it fails with:

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: bad parameter or other API misuse

Code:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(SQLiteConfiguration))]
class MyDbContext : DbContext, IMyDbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base(
```

new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|Data.db;Password='abcdef';"), true)
{
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}

```
    public DbSet<Field> Fields { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var sqliteConnectionInitializer = 
            new SqliteCreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>(modelBuilder);
        Database.SetInitializer(sqliteConnectionInitializer);
    }
}

public class SQLiteConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public SQLiteConfiguration() : base()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new 
            System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory());
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient", 
            System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance);

        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite", SQLiteFactory.Instance);
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SQLite", 
   (DbProviderServices)SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance.GetService(typeof(DbProviderServices)));
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance);
    }
}
```

Exception in full:

> System.Data.DataException: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.
>
> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
>
> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: bad parameter or other API misuse
>
> at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, String vfsName, SQLiteConnectionFlags connectionFlags, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum openFlags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool)
> at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open()
> at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher'1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action'2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action'3 executing, Action'3 executed)
> at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func'1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass174_0.b__0()
> at SQLite.CodeFirst.SqliteInitializerBase'1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction'1.PerformAction(TInput input)
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action'1 action)
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet'1.Initialize()
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet'1.get_InternalContext()
> at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery'1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
> at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable'1 source)
> at MyApp.Services.DataService.Initialize()